# beaver Builder plugin templates are unresponsive sometimes

Tags: wordpress

I used the Hope template from Beaver-builder plugin.The whole content is distorted with this template.

I want to is there any dependencies Beaver Builder have?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd9lt.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the Solution. It was issue  with ubuntu operating sytem, It does not allow BB to create upload folder in wp-content folder and when beaver builder does not find **upload** folder it renders the template badly. So run this command whenever you do not get the behavior of plugin.

> chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress/

Above command gives permission to create folder.